# Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> t' with actual type `Rat'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm doing homework and one of the tasks is to make a function that normalises a rational number. Rational numbers here are defined by two integers ( which is already determined by the professor so I can't change that). This is what I came up with:

```
data Rat = Rat Integer Integer

normaliseRat :: Rat -> Rat
normaliseRat (Rat a b) = Rat (a `div` gcd a b) (b `div` gcd a b)
```

When I try to run the function I get this error:

```
<interactive>:2:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> t' with actual type `Rat'
    * The function `normaliseRat' is applied to two value arguments,
        but its type `Rat -> Rat' has only one
      In the expression: normaliseRat 6 9
      In an equation for `it': it = normaliseRat 6 9
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:2:1)
```

I'm completely new to Haskell and functional programming so forgive me if it's a simple solution.

Comment: It seems that your code is calling `normaliseRat` with two integers, and not a `Rat`.

Comment: @Dogbert how do I fix that?

Comment: `normaliseRat 6 9` passes two integers, `normaliseRat (Rat 6 9)` passes one `Rat`.

Comment: Rather than compute `gcd a b` twice, you might want something like ``let d = gcd a b in Rat (a `div` d) (b `div` d)``. With `Data.Function.on`, that can also be written ``(Rat `on` (`div` gcd a b)) a b``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`normaliseRat` expects a single `Rat` argument, not the two integers you would use to build a `Rat` value. Assuming your `Rat` type has an appropriate `Show` instance,

```
> normaliseRat (Rat 6 9)
Rat 2 3
```

If you wanted a smart constructor for `Rat` that *did* take two `Integer` arguments, that would be something like

```
mkRat :: Integer -> Integer -> Rat
mkRat n d = let gcd' = gcd n d
                n' = n `div` gcd'
                d' = d `div` gcd'
            in Rat n' d'

> mkRat 6 9
Rat 2 3
```

(The purpose of a smart constructor is to prevent you from creating a value like `Rat 6 9` in the first place, as long as you always use `mkRat` in place of using `Rat` directly. `mkRat` can also be defined in terms of your existing `normaliseRat`:

```
mkRat :: Integer -> Integer -> Rat
mkRat n d = normaliseRat (Rat n d)
```

)

Comment: Oh my god I knew it was something simple, thank you so much!